# cant float two items inside of a grid element

Tags: css, image, css-float, css-grid

I have a grid with a bunch of items. One of the items contains an image and some text. I want to float the text next to the image but can't get it to work...

See code below:

```html
<div id="blog-post-item" class="blog-post">
    <h1>Some amazing blogpost title about something super cool!</h1>
    <div class="blog-post-content">
        <div class="content-flex-container clearfix">
            <img src="Data/Content/food_post5.jpg">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione, repellendus natus! Corporis, architecto laboriosam natus doloremque corrupti sunt a incidunt! Eligendi soluta beatae neque reprehenderit ipsa perspiciatis architecto accusantium incidunt.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    background: tomato;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(max-content, max-content);
    column-gap: 20px;
    row-gap: 20px;
}

.blog-post {
    background: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(auto, max-content) 1fr;
    height: 100%;
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    width: 100%;
}

.blog-post h1 {
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1/-1;
}

.blog-post-content {
    grid-row: 2;
}

.content-flex-container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.content-flex-container img {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.content-flex-container p {
    float: left;
}
```

But this is the result i get:
[image]

as you can see the text is below the image not to the right of the image in the big white open space..

If more information is needed please let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: Add `display:flex` to the wrapper. You will not be able to use `float` though, but it will put the elements side-by-side.

Comment: why cant i use float though?

Comment: Because float does not work in flex or grid-containers

Comment: not even if it is nested inside of another element like in my case? :O

Comment: OK, remove the float from the `p`? - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLaEgwX

Comment: wow that actually worked :D no clue how but wow. Css just keeps feeling like black magic. Post it as an answer and i will accept it.